# Force Light Mode Across Entire App - Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I'm looking to force light mode across the entirity of my app. I've read numerous posts about this subject, all of which indicate that I should set UIUserinterfaceStyle to light in the project's info pane. When I open the info pane, UIInterfacestyle isnt present. Nor is Appearance. Any idea on how I can do this?

Xcode 13.4.1, iOS app

[Info pane in my app's target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n05ut.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has changed over time...

In info.plist, add the `Appearance` key:

[image]

If you've never added a key...

Click the `+` button on an existing key:

[image]

Then type or select Appearance:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly enough "Appearance" is not present either. Is there a way to add this target property?

Comment: Click the `+` button, and type in "Appearance" -- then type in "Light" for the value. There are many, many keys which are not present by default.

Comment: Got it, didn't realize the + I was looking for was the small one within the list. This is working. Much appreciated

Comment: @DMeyer - sorry -- I forget that folks may have never done this task before :(